# ¿Cómo poner un label arriba de un input como en la imagen?

Tags: css

[image: Input parte de abajo , label "nombre"]
Buenos días quisiera saber como colocar el label "nombre" sobre el input como se muestra en la imagen.

Código html

```
    <form >
        <label class="etiqueta" for="nombre" >nombre</label> 
        <br>
        <input  class="redondeado" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre">
    </form>
```

Comment: Por favor para evitar el cierre de tu pregunta lee [ask] y trata de proveer un [mcve] que demuestre que has  intentado o investigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto se necesita agrupar cada `input` con su respectivo `label` dentro de un **div**. A éste **div** le di una clase `contenido`, lo cual tiene una `position: relative`. Entonces ya se puede coquetear con el `label` especialmente con `position: absolute`, porque su padre `contenido` es `relative` (los objetos con posición absoluto no salen).

Entonces, para ubicar donde más bien quede, se trabaja con `position: absolute`, `top`, `left` y o `margin`.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 background-color: antiquewhite
}

form .contenido {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: calc(90%);
 height: auto;
 margin: 10px auto;
 padding: 30px 10px 10px;
 background: #ccc;
}

form .contenido input {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 border-radius: 20px;
 border: 0;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 font-size: 18px;
}

form .contenido label {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: auto;
 top: 10px;
 left: 50px;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0, .3)
}
```

```html
<form>

 <div class="contenido">
  <label class="etiqueta" for="nombre">Nombre</label>  
  <input class="redondeado" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre">
 </div>
 
 <div class="contenido">
  <label class="etiqueta" for="nombre">Apellido</label>  
  <input class="redondeado" type="text" placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido">
 </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias eres genial

Comment: Si está respuesta te sirvió, marca como aceptada, para que sirva a otros que buscan el mismo problema. Con el  check puedes acepatar como respuesta